# Connect to Excel file using QODBC/QODBC3 Qt driver

Tags: c++, sql, excel, qt, odbc

How could I properly connect to Excel file using QODBC/QODBC3 Qt drivers?

At firs I built a driver like that (in cmd)

> >cd %QTPATH%\src\plugins\sqldrivers\odbc
>
> >qmake odbc.pro
>
> >nmake

then `qsqlodbc4.dll` file has been created in  `%QTPATH%\plugins\sqldrivers`

I used this code

```
    #include <QApplication>
    #include <QtGui>
    #include <QtSql>
    
    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        QApplication app(argc, argv);
        //QComboBox myCombo;
    
        //excel stuff
        QSqlDatabase dbExcel = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC","dbExcel");
            // i thought mayde that would work
           // dbExcel.setDatabaseName("C:\databases\test.xlsx");

           //i tried connection string too
          dbExcel.setDatabaseName(QString("DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xlsx)}; READONLY=FALSE; FIL={MS Excel}; DBQ=C:\databases\test.xlsx"));
        
        if(!dbExcel.open())
        {
            QSqlError er = dbExcel.lastError();
            QMessageBox::information(0, "Error", er.text());
        }
    
    
        
         //...................
    
        
    
        return app.exec();
  }
```

and there I cathed that error (it translates like:

```
[Microsoft][ODBC driver manager] Data source not found and default driver not set. QODBC3: Unable to connect
```

)

[image: error]

**UPD**

Also it says that drivers are avalible

```
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QIBASE QSQLITE QODBC3 QODBC
```

Comment: You will definitly need to use the DSN call ``dbExcel.setDatabaseName(QString("DRIVER={Mic...``.

Comment: @SebastianLange well I tried like this
`dbExcel.setDatabaseName(QString("DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xlsx)}; READONLY=FALSE; FIL={MS Excel}; DBQ=C:\databases\test.xlsx"));` 

but it didn't worked.
also made it uncommented in code to not confuse people anymore :)

Comment: @DanilGholtsman, did you get this to work for you?

Comment: @Rachael nope, not through ODBC

Comment: Darn, well I may I ask what driver you did end up using, or if you went with just parsing it as delimited text? Thanks :)

Comment: @Rachael well, I used QAxObject stuff, as far as I remember
http://qt-project.org/wiki/Using_ActiveX_Object_in_QT
http://www.qtforum.org/article/22557/activeqt-excel.html

Comment: Ah! You've made my weekend. Thank you. Another curious question. Are you using MS SQL with QT and if so, how have you been successful at connecting to it without ODBC?

Comment: @Rachael you welcome! Really good to know that I helped somebody with something. Nope, it was my previous job, there we used postgresql, as I remember. But project is closed now (it supposed to be some good tool for pertophysicists)   Now I doing some webapps stuff :P

Comment: ODBC seems to work for me with test.xls but not test.xlsx.  I get the same error as you for test.xlsx.  using Qt 5.5.1

Comment: @SketchBookGames yeah, that's sad

Answer (score 0):

Wrong:  `DBQ=C:\databases\test.xlsx`

Correct:    Use double `\` in addr

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).